# Openshift port-forwarding

Tags: java, git, netbeans, ssh, openshift

After many hours and many attempts, remains now your help.
Im trying to do **port-forwarding** to access my DB in *Openshift* on *Neatbeans*.

I've already done lots of tutorials, upgrade and downgrade versions of **net-ssh**, uninstall **rhc** and so on. I have read a lot git solutions (*ssh_options[]*...) and doesn't understand a damn thing.

When I'm trying do to port-forwarding I get this:

```
`C:\Users\andre>rhc port-forward -a leixinhos
Checking available ports ... Could not parse PKey: no start line
Usage: rhc port-forward <application>
Pass '--help' to see the full list of options
C:\Users\andre>`
```

**leixinhos** is my app name
I have everything right except this detail that prevents me from access DB on Neatbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your console output I see the following error:
`Could not parse PKey: no start line`

I also see you are running rhc on a Windows machine.

What version of Ruby do you have installed? I was getting that same error message when trying to use rhc with the latest version of Ruby on my Windows machine. In order to get all rhc commands to work correctly in windows I had to uninstall rhc, uninstall the latest version of Ruby, install Ruby version 1.9.3 and then reinstall rhc.

Comment: ruby version: ruby 2.2.2p95

Comment: omg u solvit
I needed 2 days to solvit, U DESERVE IT